# how to put an input box next to each item in a database using php

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I am currently learning PHP and HTML so please bear with me.

I have a web page that shows a table, the content of this table is from a database on the localhost which constantly gets updated (this displays our stock on hand in our warehouse).
The table has 3 columns - Item Number - Description - Quantity Available.

What I am trying to do is get input boxes next to each item so that the user can type in a quantity they would like to order.

I'm having trouble with seeing how I can do this.  My understanding is along the lines of -> 'for each item in this item number field, create an input box' but I found that I can't run a query for the list of items and create a form\input box at the same time (if this makes sense).  So I am back to square one where all I have is a list of item numbers and no idea where to go next.

(Note: In the past there has been confusion about how they user is going to pay for the order - there is no payment facilities being implemented in this - this is just about creating input boxes for a dynamically changing database.)

Thank you,
Matt

As requested - current code (apologies if I pasted it in wrong):

```
<?php
echo "<div id=header>";
echo "<h1>Stock on hand listing</h1>";
echo "<p>Stock is updated every hour during business hours</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='table.css' type='text/css'>";

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '*****', '*****');
if (!$conn) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('****_SOH',$conn);
/*  select only items with stock on hand */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_SOH where (((TABLE_SOH.ITM_ONHAND)     >0))",$conn);

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>On Hand</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ITM_NO'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ITM_DES'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=right>" . $row['ITM_ONHAND'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Can we see the code that shows the table?

Comment: Could you paste here your code you have already done?

Comment: See [`this Q&A on SO`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17757626/) which could be modified to be inputs instead of checkboxes and [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20901262/) - You will need some form of looping mechanism to do what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys Acyut answer below got me to the next stage. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already made a sql query to get the columns -item and description ,
you need to insert a php code in the sql query block like

```
<?php

  echo ("<input type ='text' name ='item'.$i >");

?>
```

That should append a text column in every row of the table. $i corresponds to each item and will help you retrieve data stored in each row.

Comment: Thanks!! That did what I was after!